# Runnable Jar file is not running on double click

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have a simple Java project, which has a file Input.java. The code for Input.java goes like this -

```
package com.src.functionalities;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int n = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
        System.out.println("You have provided : " + n);
     }

    }
```

Now, I have created an executable jar file in Eclipse by  Export -> Jar -> Executable jar file and named the jar file as test.jar.

Now, when I try to open it via command prompt, it works perfectly fine.

```
java -jar test.jar
```

But, I was expecting to open the command prompt when I double click on the runnable jar file. 
What is the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: execute via doubleclick depends on the settings of your operating system for files that ending with .jar. that has nothing to do with java.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using Windows 7, 64 bit. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: To verify your jar is running or not open your Task Manage and find that javaw process will be running (window os).

Comment: in windows you can wrap your `java -jar test.jar` in a batch file

Comment: create an exe file or make a right click -> open with -> select java

Comment: So, is it a better idea to create a runnable .exe file instead of a .jar file?

Comment: Erm ... no.  It is better to write a little BAT file; see above.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the JVM expects the app to have GUI, but your app is strictly console app. If you don't have GUI, nothing happens, since JVM normally does not invoke Windows console.

Either make a batch file for your jar or you can look into software that distributes Java applications as an exe file, doing the batch file for you, like [Install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html).

Comment: install4j is neither free nor free of charge. It doesn't offer a lot more than the existing solutions, especially launch4j and IzPack. Writing a bat script containing a single command line containing what you would enter in a terminal isn't difficult.

Comment: @gouessej There is 90 days evaluation period, which is more than enough for student/self-learner to mess around with.

Comment: It's a proprietary black box, it will learn nothing to a student/self-learner whereas there are tons of tools to do something similar, one-jar, PackR, JarMatey, several Maven-based, Gradle-based and Ant-based solutions, some build-in features in several IDEs, ... Moreover, his program is rudimentary. When he succeeds in opening a console and running Java in it with a script, he will just have to call this script within its JAR or to provide an archive containing a JAR and a script. Using install4j to do that is like using a thermonuclear bomb to kill a fly.